# QML object property changed from c++, but I can't see the result

Tags: c++, qt, qml

So I could change the property of a certain QML object via C++ code, but I couldn't see the result on screen.
I have an item repeated 64 times, and I want a certain image to be displayed only for the 32nd item (from C++) so I used invokeMethod to access the object via C++ then I used setProperty to change the visibility, if I view it with qDebug the property "visible" did change, but I notice no difference on the screen I still cannot see the image, but if I change the visibility from qml, I can see it.

This is the C++ code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQuickView view;
  view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));
  view.show();
  QQuickItem* child;
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///Board.qml")));
  QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
  QQuickItem *qmlObject = rootObject->findChild<QQuickItem*>("grid")->findChild<QQuickItem*>("repeter");
  QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qmlObject,"itemAt",Qt::DirectConnection,   Q_RETURN_ARG (QQuickItem*,child), Q_ARG(int,32));
  child=child->findChild<QQuickItem*>("pleaseWork");
  qDebug() << child->property("visible");
  child->setProperty("visible","true");
  qDebug() << child->property("visible");
  return app.exec();
}
```

I used qDebug to verify the property changed

This is the QML code :

```
Item 
{
    id: root
    width: 8*45
    height: 8*45
    Grid 
    {
        id: grid
        objectName: "grid"
        rows: 8
        Repeater 
        {
            objectName: "repeter"
            model: 64 
            Image
            {
                objectName: "test"
                width: 45; height: 45 
                source: "images/dark_square.png"
                Image
                {
                    id: isit
                    objectName: "pleaseWork"
                    visible: false
                    source: "images/avail_dark.png"
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly if you want other people to look at it – thanks!

Comment: Too bad there is nothing to indent in the C++ code

Comment: I'm speaking of the QML. C++ looks good.

Comment: Btw. all tabs must be replaced by spaces on Stackoverflow and you must add 4 spaces before each code line.

Comment: Readable enough now? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Typical QML code puts the `{` on the same line as the Component name but that's fine now :)

Comment: Are you taking of the correct element in the argument of [itemAt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#itemAt-method)? The 32nd element is at index 31.

Comment: That wouldn't matter much as the items are all similar, I just need to change some of their properties individually

Comment: You have a problem: `child->setProperty("visible","true");` sets a string, not a bool value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QQuickView` and `QQmlApplicationEngine` are alternative ways to load and show QML views. What you are loading into `QQmlApplicationEngine` has nothing to do with the visible output of `QQuickView`.

In order to get things running, you need to change the top element of the QML file from `Item` to `Window` and show it on screen:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///Board.qml")));
// end of your code

QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(rootObject);
if (!window) {
    qDebug() << "Error: Your root item has to be a window.";
    return -1;
}
window->show();

// continue with your code
QQuickItem *qmlObject = rootObject->findChild<QQuickItem*>("grid")->findChild<QQuickItem*>("repeter");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just started learning Qt and I didn't know that there were many ways to load and show QML, thanks again for your help

Comment: But do you know of any way I can use to the QQmlApplicationEngine instead?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code works fine with QQmlApplicationEngine. You just need to get and show the windows as I posted.

Comment: I think you should remove the QQuickView because QQmlApplicationEngine is more flexible.